# How do I incorporate an options object as a parameter when I want to support an infinite amount of arguments?

Tags: javascript

I am accepting an infinite amount of arguments and looping through whatever the user provides. I would like to incorporate an options object into this module, but I am not sure how that would work. Would this code just see the options object as one of the normal params?

```
    module.exports = function () {
      var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
      var masterObject = [];

      args.forEach(function (array) {
        array.map(function (item) {
          var found = false;

          for (var i = 0; i < masterObject.length; i++) {
            if (masterObject[i].word === item.word) {
              masterObject[i].count += item.count;
              found = true;
            }
          }

         if (!found) {
            masterObject.push(item);
          }
        });
      });
      return masterObject;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you need to decide between

```
var mymodule = require('mymodule')(opts);
mymodule(1, 2, 3);
```

and

```
var mymodule = require('mymodule');
mymodule(1, 2, 3, opts);
```

or something else. The first one:

```
module.exports = function (opts) {
  return function() {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    // ...
  };
};
```

The second one:

```
module.exports = function (opts) {
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
  opts = args.pop();
  // ...
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I like Amadan's response to this problem, I just wanted to add a related note:

What I see more often than not: APIs that accept an **infinite** number of values, AND accept options, will use the combination of an array (to contain the n-length values) and an object to pass in the options.

This way you don't need any voodoo, and your API is super clean:

```
module.exports = function (array, opts) { 
   // parse your options 
   opts = opts || {};

   // loop over array
   array.forEach(item => {
     // to infinity, and beyond!
 });
}
```

If you want to go crazy, and can use [ES6 Rest Parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters), but if you did that, the options parameter would have to be supplied first (and if the user didn't have any options to pass, they would have to use `null` or an empty object, which could be weird for some APIs, but it's a possible way to approach this problem):

```
module.exports = function (opts, ...args) {
    // do something with your options
    opts.foo = opts.foo || true;

    // now loop through your infinite args
    args.forEach(item => {
     console.log(item);
  });
}
```